# Is there a way to preserve or modify in-code radix information?

Tags: java, parsing, radix

Let's say I have the following code:

```
int two = 2;
String twoInBinary = Integer.toString(two, 2);
```

The `twoInBinary` String will now hold the value `10`.  But it seems like the radix information is completely lost in this transformation.  So, if I send `twoInBinary` as part of an XML file over a network and want to deserialize it into its integer format, like this...

```
int deserializedTwo = Integer.parseInt(twoInBinary);
```

... then `deserializedTwo` will equal `10` rather than `2` (in decimal).

I know there is the `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`, but in a complex system using many different radixes for many different strings, is it possible to preserve the radix information without having to keep a separate, synchronized log with your values?

Comment: XML has no standard for this but you could invent one e.g. like Java 7 uses `0` for octal `0x` for hex, `0b` for binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, not in standard Java. It is, however, trivial to write a `Serializable` class that can transfer the value and radix information over the wire.

```
class ValueWithRadix implements Serializable
{
    int radix;
    String value;
}

int deserializedTwo = Integer.parseInt( valueWithRadix.getValue() , valueWithRadix.getRadix() );
```

Edit: To clarify yet more, the XML on the wire might then look like

```
<ValueWithRadix>
  <value>10</value>
  <radix>2</radix>
</ValueWithRadix>
```

rather than just

```
<value>10</value>
```

which of course doesn't preserve radix information.

Cheers,

Comment: @Peter The OP mentioned "over a network", thus I figured marshalling/unmarshalling and thus `Serializable`...

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending it as part of an XML file, you have to use the correct datatype definition.  XML schema supports a [lot of different built-intypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes) to describe your types accurately.

So `<value>10</value>` might currently be describing an `integer`, which is defined as base 10.  You could quite easily describe a new simple type which expresses digits as base 2.